# error page "Not Found" when cxf-spring boot integration tests

Tags: spring, maven, soap, spring-boot, cxf

I am trying to develop for the first time a soap jax-ws web service with Apache CXF and Spring boot; I'm really noviste in the use of these technologies. For this, I created a web application type maven project intended to implement my web layer Service (knowing that the dao layers and profession will be called via an addiction that is actually a project maven java application with spring boot). and all coupled in an enterprise app.

Then I built Apache cxf and spring boot in the web project like this, my pom.xml:

> com.xxx.dev
>       module-web
>       0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>       war
>       
>           ${project.build.directory}/endorsed
>           UTF-8

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-xml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>mobilepayment-dao</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-xml</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mavencentral</id>
        <name>Maven Central</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my spring boot configuration class:

> @Configuration
>   @ImportResource({"classpath:cxf-servlet.xml"})
>   public class MyConfig {

```
@Autowired(required=true)
private Bus bus;

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servlet;
}

@Bean
public IServicesWeb momoService() {
    return new MomoServices();
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, momoService());
    endpoint.publish("/momo");
    return endpoint;
} }
```

The web service interface:

> @WebService public interface IServicesWeb extends IMetierGestionCompte

the implementation class:

> @Component
>   @WebService
>   public class MomoServices implements IServicesWeb{

```
private IMetierGestionCompte gcMetier;

public void setGcMetier(MetierImplGestionCompte gcMetier) {
    this.gcMetier = gcMetier;
}

@WebMethod
@Override
public void ajouterCompte( ) {
    gcMetier.ajouterCompte( );
}
```

Web project is deployed very well on Wildfly with a "hello world" at "http: // localhost: 8080 / web-mobilepayment /"

My concern is that when I try to check my web services and the addresses wsdl: "http: // localhost: 8080 / web-mobilepayment / services" and "http: // localhost: 8080 / web-mobilepayment / services? wsdl "nothing appears (no trace of the integration cxf-spring boot) if it is not a message" not found "
I don't understand why my web services don't work, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your "hello world" is displayed by your web servlet under `web-mobilepayment`. If you want to access webservices, you have to use CXF servlet path under `/services/`.

You published your webservice with `momo` path, so you have to call `http://localhost: 8080/services/momo?wsdl`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When i have call  http://localhost: 8080/services/momo?wsdl ; i receive error page from wildfly with the message "404 - Not Found". I tried to find wsdl file in my classpath, but i don't see it

Comment: And what happens when you call http://localhost: 8080/services/ ? You should at least have an answer from CXF servlet.

Comment: when i call localhost: 8080/services/? ; i have the same error page. I have remarked that my project don't contains some wsdl file. I don't understand the reason

Comment: Why do you want to deploy a Spring Boot app (with a CXF web service) into a Wildfly instance (which I assume you are doing)? Spring Boot does provide you with everything needed to serve your web services, no additional container needed - check: https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter . If you still want to deploy it, you should edit your question - because it is more a "how to deploy a Spring Boot app with CXF into a JBoss Wildfly" question. Additionally, I think this error is due to some non-synchronized path-mappings between Spring Boot & Wildfly, would give it a google ;)